# What does Dagger do? Explain in words that an high-school Java programmer can understand

Tags: android

It is based on the Java Specification Request (JSR) 330. It uses code generation and is based on annotations. The generated code is very relatively easy to read and debug.

1) Dagger provide simplifies access to shared instances
- That means If we declare @Inject annotation in our code then we can get reference everywhere in our projects

2) Easy configuration of complex dependencies

- dagger follow the implicit order and generate Objects so in dependency and generated code both are easy to understand and traced and we can reduce large boilerplate of code,
- normally we can hand to obtain reference and pass them to other objects so we can focus on modules the build rather then focusing the order in which they need to be created

3) Easier unit and integration testing Because  dependency graph is created for us so its easily swap out module,network response